# Why is my Google OAuth URL placing a hash in my returned URL?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

**THE GIVEN URL:**

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&state=drive&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.woktop.com%2Fnewservice.php&response_type=token&client_id=889314330670.apps.googleusercontent.com

**THE RETURN URL:**

> http://www.woktop.com/newservice.php#state=drive&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZRtTRmpakw5qa0SejLsC0qzNNb9R6GYF0xZGt_uphe3WfeeZng&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

The return URL completely works if the `#` is changed to a `?` (to start the query string).  Why in the world is Google returning a `#` and thus *"killing the query string"*?

**SEPARATE NOTE:**

On a separate note, I don't quite know if I should be requesting `token` or `code` as a response type.  I'm planning to have users attach their Google Drive account(s) to an account on my website.  I have read through the documentation multiple times and I can't quite figure out which one is better for my website?  For now (in the example above) I go with token.  Also, depending on which one I go with, what should I store in my database for future use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because I was requesting a `token` instead of a `code`.  When I received code, the URL was formatted without a hash (`#`), but rather formatted as a query string.  The reason for this is unclear to me, but the documentation states that `token` should only be used as a response type for a heavy-Javascript application.  The API code I was writing is in PHP, so `code` is the clearly appropriate choice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you do with `code` afterwards?

Comment: I'm not sure I remember, but if I had to guess I probably made API requests with it or then requested back to the OAuth provider for an access token.

Comment: but doesn't code require you to put username and password instead of just token? I'm having the same problem, but I need to use 'token' not 'code'