# Passport Js Google Oauth2.0 adding a # in the end of the Express Redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

#### Scenario

Using Google OAuth 2.0 using Passport Js in Express Js.
The google strategy works fine but upon successful log in, I am using `res.redirect('/')` but it gets the url `http://localhost:3000/#` which affects my `req.session` as I am not able to get that in that ('/') route. But when refreshed by `http://localhost:3000`, the `req.session` provides the details.

#### Code

```js
const validatedUser=(req,res,next)=>{
    if(!req.session.isValidated || req.session.isValidated===undefined)
        res.redirect('/login')
    else
    {
        next();
    }
}

app.get('/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google',{
    failureRedirect:'/login',
    failureFlash: true,
    successFlash: true,
    session: true
}),(req,res)=>{
    req.session.isValidated=true
    console.log({LOGIN : req.session})
    res.redirect('/')
})
app.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
    console.log({LOGOUT: req.session})
    console.log(req.session.passport)   
    req.logout()
    req.session.destroy()
    res.redirect('/login')
})
app.get('/',validatedUser,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.session)
    res.render('index')
})
```

#### OUTPUT :

- Just after login URL : `http://localhost:3000/#`

```js
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-05-30T17:05:56.576Z,
    originalMaxAge: 7200000,
    httpOnly: false,
    sameSite: true,
    secure: false
  }
}
```

But my desired output is

```js
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-05-30T17:05:56.566Z,
    originalMaxAge: 7200000,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: true
  },
  passport: {
    user: {
      profile: [Object],
      token: 'ACCOUNT_TOKEN'
    }
  }
}
```

this is the output I get when I refresh to `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Maybe this post help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695834/why-is-my-google-oauth-url-placing-a-hash-in-my-returned-url

Comment: Not helping... Coz there is am issue that i am not getting ```req.session``` with passport profile details in ```http://localhost:3000/#```